# How to plugin and deplug css file via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

For an example I want JS to switch attached CSS files after some events (this events can't be realized through css @media function)

How to make it most compact and easy way?

Answer (score 2):

To add or remove a CSS file dynamically using JavaScript, you can use the following approach:

1. Create a link element for the CSS file:

```js
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/css";
link.href = "path/to/your/css/file.css";
```

2. To add the CSS file to the document, append the link element to the head element:

```js
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

3. To remove the CSS file, remove the link element from the head element:

```js
document.head.removeChild(link);
```

Here's an example function that toggles the CSS file:

```js
function toggleCSS() {
  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.rel = "stylesheet";
  link.type = "text/css";
  link.href = "path/to/your/css/file.css";

  var head = document.head;
  var existingLink = head.querySelector("link[rel='stylesheet']");

  if (existingLink) {
    head.removeChild(existingLink);
  } else {
    head.appendChild(link);
  }
}
```

When you call this function, it will toggle the CSS file on and off each time it's called.

Comment: This would remove the first link-tag (even if it not the on previously inserted.

I suggest you change to

var existingLink = head.querySelector(`link[href="${link.href}"]`);

which would remove the link with the specific href.

Answer (score 0):

When you only need to *toggle* a few CSS rules you can load all CSS and put the CSS that needs to be toggled/overridden in its own `<style>` block last in line in `<head>`.

Give the `<style>` to be toggled an ID or classname and simply toggle the styles' `disabled` *attribute*.

Below snippet contains a simple proof of concept. [This Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/zYPKEVL?editors=1000) shows an elaborate demo toggling all kinds of styles of a page.

**BTW** this also works for `<link rel="stylesheet" id="some-external-style" href="...">`. Simply get the reference in JS and toggle its `disabled` attribute.

```js
var styleElement = document.getElementById('toggled-style');

function toggleStyle() {
  styleElement.disabled = !styleElement.disabled;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style id="always-active">
    /* All your regular CSS */
    
    body {
      background-color: CornSilk;
      color: CornflowerBlue;
    }
  </style>

  <style id="toggled-style">
    /* Style en/disabled by event trigger */

    /*
       These rules override any defined rules in 'always-active'
       when 'toggles-style' is not disabled.
    */
    body {
      background-color: CornflowerBlue;
      color: CornSilk;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>some content</p>
  <button onclick="toggleStyle()">toggle</button>
</body>
```